# Is it possible to link the Office Hub to multiple live.com or OneDrive accounts simultaneously?

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-account, office-hub

Phone is set to my personal Window’s account and the Office Hub shows the OneDrive account associated with that same Windows account correctly.

What I do not see is a way to use the Office Hub to reach my company’s OneDrive (a completely different Window’s Account) and the files stored on that secondary Window’s account ***as a first class citizen*** (I can of course email a share link, but that isn’t my ideal).

Comment: I suggest starting the tag Windows-Account as the newer version of Live-id.

Comment: The phone does refer to it as "Windows Live" - by all means [start a thread on meta](http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to see if a consensus can be reached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible-like you said, the Office Hub forces you to use your primary Windows account. The best you can do is install the dedicated OneDrive application and set it up using your company's account.